How to add an additional icon at the bottom of the splash screen in the android 12+ and needs to work with the lowest models as well
I need to show a splash screen with the Appicon at the center and an additional logo at the bottom of the splash screen.
How to add the additional icon at the bottom of the splash screen in the android
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Please share code you tried.

You should use the splash screen api https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate
And then in there define a windowSplashScreenBrandingImage:

You can use windowSplashScreenBrandingImage to set an image to be shown at the bottom of the splash screen. However, the design guidelines recommend against using a branding image.

<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/branding_image_logo</item>


